# Get the value from callback

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I need help. I was trying to extract the value inside a callback function I want to make it available globally or anywhere outside a function but not quite sure how to do it. I am still trying to learn javascript.

Down below is a snippet of a callback function named **updateBidAsk**. What it does is, it gets the price feed from a source in a json format and updates all the time whenever there is new price. I placed it inside **.each()** function to process and iterate each data and extract the value of bid price which is **quoteViewModel.bid** and store it in a global variable called **currentBidPrice**. Now if console.log it shows the price.

However my problem is I don't know how to pass the data inside **getVals()** to be passed into **getPrices** function. I have tried calling the **getVals** functions inside **getPrices** function but with no success, I am always getting undefined every time I call the function. how can I correctly pass the data from updateBidAsk to --> getPrices function? Here's my code. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
chat.client.updateBidAsk = function(rawData) {
  $.each(rawData,
    function() {

      var quoteViewModel = formatQuote(this);
      var $row = $(rowTemplate.supplant(quoteViewModel));
      $stockTableBody.find('tr[data-symbol=' + this.symbol + ']').replaceWith($row).fadeIn("fast");

      //if block, checks for eursd bid price updates
      if (quoteViewModel.symbol === 'EURUSD') {
        currentBidPrice = quoteViewModel.bid;
      } //end if block

    }); // end callback function

  //if I console.log it shows the price
  //console.log(currentBidPrice);

  getVals(currentBidPrice);

}; //end of callback function updateBidAsk

function getVals(data){
  //console.log(data);
  return data; 
}

$.getJSON('http://somevalidname.com/chart/eurusd/1', getPrices); // handles the data from source

function getPrices(data) {

  // I just need to get the passed data from function getVals() 
  // and somehow make it available here so I could use.
  //

}
```

Comment: Your logical flow is flawed.  Instead of finding a way to pass the value from the callback outside, the _callback_ should be making the call to do something with the data which is returned.  Otherwise, as you've seen, you might get an undefined value, and in any case even if not you can't rely on that always being true.

Comment: *"I don't know how to pass the data to another function."* By passing the data as argument when you call the function: `anotherFunction(data)`.

Comment: Thank you very much @TimBiegeleisen for the tip. Am also looking for the possibilities of rewriting the code. haha.

Comment: But hopefully what I said makes sense (and is correct?).  You know you have the data when the callback returns, so rely on it being there at that point.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Felix kling. but my prob is I need to pass the value inside another function. 

for example in the code snippet above. 


chat.client.updateBidAsk = function(rawData){

...some code here....

getVals(currentBidPrice); // is called inside the callback updateBidAsk

}

function getVals(data){
   //console.log(data); <-- this produces data is passed successfully.
   I need to pass the value inside data parameter to another function 
}

function anotherFunction(){

   prob is how can I pass the value inside here?? 

}

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3VqKqt5